# Azure: Secure score recommendation debian errors

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, debian

Note: I am new to Azure.

I have created "Web App" using nodeJS 14.16, created docker "linux" container (FROM node:14.16 AS build) and published to Azure Web services, it works fine.

But on the security side (Security Check) I am getting lot of errors like below:

"Debian Security Update for gmp (DLA 2837-1)" "Debian Security Update for libwebp (DLA 2677-1)" "Debian Security Update for nss (DLA 2836-1)".

TBH, I am not sure where these errors comes from and how to resolve these errors. Even I have not used these packages in my nodeJS application. Could anyone please give me an idea or provide any thoughts to resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot from Azure portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have Microsoft Defender for Cloud: **Defender for Containers** enabled for your subscription. Defender for Containers includes an integrated vulnerability scanner for scanning images in Azure Container Registry registries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-introduction?tabs=defender-for-container-arch-aks

In your question, you say you are using `NodeJS 14.16` which it looks like needs to be updated to `14.16.1`.  Once you push a new version to your ACR, Defender for Containers should rescan you repo and clear this findings in a couple hours.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.16.1/

Comment: Hi,

First of all sorry for delayed reply.

Thanks for your suggestion and we overcome this issue by updating docker image (nodeJS) using latest bullseye package. Like the following one:

FROM node:14.19.0-bullseye